# Determine the Type and the General Solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Not sure where to start with this question. It's got me very confused. Help would be very appreciated, thanks

**Question**

Identify the type of first order ode and hence find the general solution:

$$t \dot x = x+2te^{- {x\over t}}$$

Comment: Maple gives $x(t) = \ln(2\ln(t)+c)\cdot t$

Comment: the equation has changed after editing

Comment: sorry  about  typo, ok now?

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Starting with $$x'=\frac{x}{t}+2 e^{\frac{x}{t}}$$ first make $x=t z$. Doing so, the equation becomes $$tz'=2e^z$$ that is to say $$t\frac{dz}{dt}=2e^z$$ which is now separable.

I am sure that you can take from here.